# How can I run android app on from react native

Tags: react-native

I am facing error while running `react native cli` to emulator by using android studio

### Actual output

Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

### expected output

Running app on. android emulator
with custom app launch icon

### actual output with VSCode

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Try to run from android studio and see the logs.

Answer (score 0):

since the port is mentioned it looks a little bit like you are not connected and need to reconnect your adb server to the application on metro. To do so you need to install adb tools (I believe it was via brew, but google will help) and then run(in 2nd Terminal beside metro):

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

When it shows 8081 in the new terminal, you can try again.